# avoid repeating the same code when using inheritance

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this class

```
struct IDebug {
    virtual void print(std::ostream&) const = 0;
};
```

and the prints should follow some format defined for each class implementing `IDebug`.

the format is static in the sense that for a certain implementation will always have the same format and that I want the format to be used regardless of whether I have any instance of the class (for example at program initialization)

so I added a:

```
static std::string format();
```

to each of the implementing class. ugly (because it's not forced by the interface) but I could live with that

now I wanted to add some validation in the interface level that the actual `print()` is following the format this class defines. in order to do that I had to make a modification:

```
struct IDebug {
   void print(std::ostream& o) const { // no longer virtual
     auto format = format_impl();
     // preprocess using format
     print_impl(o);
     // postprocess using format
   }

protected:
   virtual void print_impl(std::ostream& o) const = 0;
   virtual std::string format_impl() const = 0;
};
```

and each of the implementing classes now have the exact same line of code:

**`std::string format_impl() const override { return format(); }`**

```
struct MooDebug : public IDebug { 
    // rest of the code
    static std::string format() { return "whatever"; } // this was already here. sadly the interface couldn't force it
    std::string format_impl() const override { return format(); } // all implementing classes are repeating this exact line
};
```

I'm looking for advice how to avoid it or make it better.

Comment: Why are you making `format_impl` pure virtual?

Comment: Why bother with the `format_impl` function, if all it's going to do is call `format()` anyway? Why not call `format()` directly instead? Or if you want to *possibly* override it for different formats later, then don't make it a pure virtual, and implement it in the `IDebug` class.

Comment: This sounds like you mean to use the template method design pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because it can't call the implementation static methods?

Comment: @CinCout how else you gonna do it?

Comment: Okay, I now see what you mean, it is a little unclear I think. In that case, why have the `static` function at all? Why not just have the `format_impl` function return the actual format? And IMO this is more of a design problem than a code or implementation problem.

Comment: because I want to be able to use the format as a static method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of some CRTP like class to create a base class that does what you want:

```
struct MooDebug : DebugHelper<MooDebug>
{
static std::string format() { return "whatever"; }
};

 template<typename T>
struct DebugHelper : IDebug
 {
     std::string format_impl() const override { return T::format(); }
  };
```

Note that in CRTP you actually cast your this pointer to `T&` and call a method that way.

Alternative in C++17 (haven't tested this), you can pass values to a template. As I never did this with strings, it might not work.

```
 template<auto T>
struct DebugHelper : IDebug
 {

  static std::string format() { return T; } 
  std::string format_impl() const override { return T; }
  };

  struct MooDebug : DebugHelper< "whatever">
   {};
```

Comment: that's nice. I'm still not sure how the IDebug will use the format_impl to run the validation it should run

Answer (score 0):

based on @JVApen answer I ended up doing this:

```
template <class T>
struct IDebug {
   void print(std::ostream& o) const { // no longer virtual
     auto myformat = T::format();
     // preprocess using format
     print_impl(o);
     // postprocess using format
   }

protected:
   virtual void print_impl(std::ostream& o) const = 0;
};
```

now we also force (up to not using the CRTP correctly) the static implementation of format() which is a nice added bonus